# Backgroung image for a table

Tags: html, css, tags, css-selectors

How can we integrate a picture as a background image for a table..

```
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><textarea>Some data here.....</textarea>
  </td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><textarea>Some data here.....</textarea>
  </td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you asking how to assign a background image to a table? Like for any other HTML element.

In CSS:

```
table.mytable
 { background-image: url(your_image.gif); }
```

In HTML:

```
<table class="mytable">
```

Reference:

[background-image property at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-image.asp)

see that page for the additional parameters `background-repeat` and `background-position`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the background for the table-row will appear above the background of the table, and the table-cell background-image will appear above that of the table-row, so you might need/want to assign `background-color: transparent;` to `tr, td`.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    background-image: url(/images/foo.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

following on from Pekka's example.

```
table.mytable td
 { background-image: url(your_image.gif); }
```

would let you put a background image in each cell

if you applied a class attribute to the `<td class="myClass">` you could then add a custom background to individual cells.

Answer (score 0):

inline css like - style="background-image: url(your_image.gif);" - 
is not quite good.

in my opinion best way to put bg to table is ;

html : table > tr > td.wide

css : table tr td.wide{background:#ffffff url(/images/bg.png) repeat;}